# how to retrieve data from more than one table

Tags: sql, left-join

Schema:-

```
Part(pid, pname, price) 

Supplier(sid, sname,city)

Part_Supplier(sid, pid)
```

Q1) Get the supplier_id and the name for those suppliers who supply all parts.

Q2) Get the part_id and name for those parts where the price of the part is greater than 3000 and is supplied by more than 3 suppliers.

Kindly help me with this as I am not able to figure this out. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like homework.. is it ?

Comment: Thanks for replying.....Gaby.....true...I am new to SQL and have no clue....It will be a great help if I get the sollution!

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and we'll show you where you've gone wrong

Comment: Where are you experts? Please give me a solution for this!!!!!!

Comment: It would be rather silly to just blatantly post the answer, you'd always come back to ask for more. It would however be way more helpful to teach you how to get your answer, so you can solve any future question you have yourself.

Comment: What cheating you are talking about Niklas?????  If you know how to solve it, then teach me......dont try to act smart.....If you know, its good...but you dont have to brag about it.

Comment: Edit your question to show us what you've tried.

Comment: I have not tried any thing as i do not have ample knowledge about it....If you think you can still help me ...then please do it.

Comment: I remember posting similar questions and comments when I started college. You'll learn pretty quickly that no one has any time to help people who won't help themselfs. You need to learn some basic SQL, then attempt the question and then if you have a specific problem, try to find the answer online and if that fails post a question here.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you shouldn't ask questions like this. You would easily be able to solve this problem if you did a basic SQL tutorial. Try this one: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Pay particular attention to SQL joins.